# Is there a way to call a function everytime a letter is entered in a QInputDialog() in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

So I'm making a really **simple notepad GUI** using `PyQt5`, and I have this `Find` feature, which will search the occurrence of the keyword inside the `QTextEdit()` entry. I want my app to update the highlighted text everytime a new character is entered. Is this possible in PyQt5?

Here's how my functions look

```
 def find(self):
    self.find_text = QInputDialog()
    self.find_text.getText(self, "Search Text", "Find:")
    self.find_text.textValueChanged.connect(self.select)


def select(self):
    print('sd')
    print(self.find_text.textValue())
```

Comment: Simply bind your find function to `QTextEdit`'s `textChanged` event …

Comment: @Programmer I edited my post. Can you please take a look at my functions? It still don't output anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [textValueChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#textValueChanged) signal of QInputDialog.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QInputDialog,
    QPushButton,
    QTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button = QPushButton("Find")
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.input_dialog = QInputDialog()
        self.input_dialog.setWindowTitle("Search Text")
        self.input_dialog.setLabelText("Find:")

        self.input_dialog.textValueChanged.connect(self.search)
        button.clicked.connect(self.input_dialog.show)

    def search(self, text):
        print("search: ", text)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note: don't use static methods like getText().

Comment: Sir, it still won't print anything

Comment: sir I edited my post. Can you please take a look at it? Thank you so much!

Comment: @cheese  see my demo

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!